# Avoiding for loops when subsetting pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, loops, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas DataFrame **df_R** that looks like this:

```
         Change       Date  SubsetCondId
0      0.000230 2015-02-13           868
1     -0.000080 2015-02-16           868
2      0.000380 2015-02-17           868
3     -0.000430 2015-02-13           679
4      0.000000 2015-02-16           679
5      0.000000 2015-02-17           679
6      0.004075 2015-02-13            10
7      0.000000 2015-02-16            10
8      0.001598 2015-02-17            10
9      0.015038 2015-02-13           937
10     0.000000 2015-02-16           937
```

In order to create a new DataFrame **R** that displays the **Date** as indexes and the **SubsetCondId** as columns I did the following:

```
factorsId = np.sort(df_R['SubsetCondId'].unique())
dates = np.sort(df_R['Date'].unique())
R = pd.DataFrame(index=dates, columns=factorsId)
for fac_id in factorsId:
    dates_id = df_R['Date'][df_R['SubsetCondId']==fac_id]
    R_id = np.array(df_R['Change'][df_R['SubsetCondId']==fac_id])
    R.loc[dates_id,fac_id] = R_id

R = R.fillna(value=0)
```

As the set of data gets larger, the process gets slower. Is there a different way to deal with this problem, maybe a vectorized approach?

Comment: df.set_index('Date') would display Date as index

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `pivot` method to set a given column as an index and values from another column as  [shown here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

```
df_R.pivot(index='Date',columns='SubsetCondId',values='Change')
```

Comment: To the downvoter : I think the code would work correctly and also has been accepted as an answer. Could you please elaborate why the downvote ?

Answer (score 0):

Use set_index combined with pivot

```
df_R = df_R.set_index('Date').pivot(columns = 'SubsetCondId')
```